# Generating a weighted average value with data from pandas and a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
             SALES 
Date                       
2018-03-31  123090     
2018-04-30  116591      
2018-05-31  119581      
2018-06-30  117544      
2018-07-31  129574      
2018-08-31  118876      
2018-09-30  129467      
2018-10-31  126062     
2018-11-30  128552     
2018-12-31  104994     
2019-01-31  149188      
2019-02-28  118204
```

And a dictionary, *price*:

```
{Oct: 11, Nov: 23, Dec: 34, Jan: 20, Feb: 30, Mar: 31, Apr: 22, May: 
23, Jun: 34, Jul: 20, Aug: 30, Sep: 31}
```

I want to calculate a weighted average price by multiplying each of the sales figures from the DataFrame with the corresponding months from the dictionary and then dividing by the total sales figures. i.e. taking the sales for of *126062* for October from the dataframe and then multiplying it by 11 (*Oct*) from the dictionary.

I have tried adding a month column and re-ordering the dataframe and then use an ordered dictionary but I feel like I am using the proverbial sledge hammer for this problem.

```
             SUM  MONTH
Date                       
2019-01-31  129188.1      1
2019-02-28  118304.5      2
2018-03-31  123090.6      3
2018-04-30  116591.2      4
2018-05-31  119581.5      5
2018-06-30  117544.0      6
2018-07-31  129574.9      7
2018-08-31  118876.2      8
2018-09-30  109467.5      9
2018-10-31  126062.0     10
2018-11-30  128552.9     11
2018-12-31  104994.2     12
```

I have also tried to look at zip and iterating over both the dataframe and dictionary but I'm struggling to find the best way to map the two datasets together.

I am happy to convert the dictionary to another dataframe if that makes it easier?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` with a DatetimeIndex method `strftime`:

Where df, dataframe and dd, dictionary of waits are defined as,

```
d = {'SALES': {pd.Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00'): 123090,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-04-30 00:00:00'): 116591,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00'): 119581,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-06-30 00:00:00'): 117544,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-07-31 00:00:00'): 129574,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-08-31 00:00:00'): 118876,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-09-30 00:00:00'): 129467,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-10-31 00:00:00'): 126062,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-11-30 00:00:00'): 128552,
  pd.Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00'): 104994,
  pd.Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'): 149188,
  pd.Timestamp('2019-02-28 00:00:00'): 118204}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

dd = {'Oct': 11, 'Nov': 23, 'Dec': 34, 'Jan': 20, 'Feb': 30, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 22,'May': 
23, 'Jun': 34, 'Jul': 20, 'Aug': 30,'Sep': 31}
```

Use

```
df['Adj Sales'] = df.index.strftime('%b').map(dd) * df['SALES']
```

Output:

```
             SALES  Adj Sales
2018-03-31  123090    3815790
2018-04-30  116591    2565002
2018-05-31  119581    2750363
2018-06-30  117544    3996496
2018-07-31  129574    2591480
2018-08-31  118876    3566280
2018-09-30  129467    4013477
2018-10-31  126062    1386682
2018-11-30  128552    2956696
2018-12-31  104994    3569796
2019-01-31  149188    2983760
2019-02-28  118204    3546120
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works great. Out of interest, if I wanted to do the same for future prices so my price dictionary contained the month and future year {Oct-19: 12} etc how could I use map but extract the month from the dictionary as i don't think I could strip it or use strftime?

Comment: You can still use strftime.   `strftime('%b-%y')` should work.

Comment: dd =  {'Oct-19': 11, 'Nov-19': 23, ... ,'Sep-20': 31}. If I try and use:

df['Adj Sales'] = df.index.strftime('%b').map(dd.strftime('%b') * df['SALES']

it throws a 'dict' object has no attribute 'strftime'?

Comment: `df.index.strftime('%b-%y).map(dd)`... you don't need to do anyting to the dictionary.  Just modify the index side

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the weights column:

```
my_dict = {'Oct': 11, 'Nov': 23, 'Dec': 34, 
           'Jan': 20, 'Feb': 30, 'Mar': 31, 
           'Apr': 22, 'May': 23, 'Jun': 34, 
           'Jul': 20, 'Aug': 30, 'Sep': 31}
weights = pd.Series(my_dict)

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index(df.Date.dt.strftime("%b"),
             inplace=True)

df['Weights'] = weights

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

then `df` is:

```
    Date        SALES   Weights
0   2018-03-31  123090  31
1   2018-04-30  116591  22
2   2018-05-31  119581  23
3   2018-06-30  117544  34
4   2018-07-31  129574  20
5   2018-08-31  118876  30
6   2018-09-30  129467  31
7   2018-10-31  126062  11
8   2018-11-30  128552  23
9   2018-12-31  104994  34
10  2019-01-31  149188  20
11  2019-02-28  118204  30
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:
First create the `'weight'` column:

```
df['weight'] = [month[ind_month] for ind_month in df.index.month_name().str[:3].values]

Out[48]:
            Sales  weight
2018-03-31    100      31
2018-04-30    101      22
2018-05-31    102      23
2018-06-30    103      34
2018-07-31    104      20
2018-08-31    105      30
2018-09-30    106      31
2018-10-31    107      11
2018-11-30    108      23
2018-12-31    109      34
2019-01-31    110      20
2019-02-28    111      30
2019-03-31    112      31
2019-04-30    113      22
```

where:

```
 month = {'Oct': 11,'Nov': 23,'Dec': 34, 'Jan': 20, 'Feb': 30, 'Mar': 31,'Apr': 22, 'May': ^M
   ...: 23, 'Jun': 34, 'Jul': 20,'Aug': 30, 'Sep': 31}
```

and then mulitply columns:

```
df['weighted_Sales'] = df.weight * df.Sales
```

which produces:

```
    Out[50]:
             Sales  weight  weighted_Sales
2018-03-31    100      31            3100
2018-04-30    101      22            2222
2018-05-31    102      23            2346
2018-06-30    103      34            3502
2018-07-31    104      20            2080
2018-08-31    105      30            3150
2018-09-30    106      31            3286
2018-10-31    107      11            1177
2018-11-30    108      23            2484
2018-12-31    109      34            3706
2019-01-31    110      20            2200
2019-02-28    111      30            3330
2019-03-31    112      31            3472
2019-04-30    113      22            2486
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a price dataframe out of dictionary

```
dict_p = {"Oct": 11, "Nov": 23, "Dec": 34, "Jan": 20, "Feb": 30, "Mar": 31, "Apr": 22, "May": 23, "Jun": 34, "Jul": 20, "Aug": 30, "Sep": 31}
dict_m = {"Oct": 10, "Nov": 11, "Dec": 12, "Jan": 1, "Feb": 2, "Mar": 3, "Apr": 4, "May": 5, "Jun": 6, "Jul": 7, "Aug": 8, "Sep": 9}

import pandas as pd

price = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_p, orient = "index", columns = ["price"])
month = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_m, orient = "index", columns = ["month"])

df_price = pd.concat([price, month],axis = 1)
print(df_price)
```

Produces:

```
 price  month
Oct     11     10
Nov     23     11
Dec     34     12
Jan     20      1
Feb     30      2
Mar     31      3
Apr     22      4
May     23      5
Jun     34      6
Jul     20      7
Aug     30      8
Sep     31      9
```

Step 2. Merge price and sales data

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_sales["month"] = df_sales.index.month

df = df_sales.merge(df_price)
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
     SALES  month  price
0   123090      3     31
1   116591      4     22
2   119581      5     23
3   117544      6     34
4   129574      7     20
5   118876      8     30
6   129467      9     31
7   126062     10     11
8   128552     11     23
9   104994     12     34
10  149188      1     20
11  118204      2     30
```

Step 3. Calculate weights and compute weighted average price

```
df["weight"] = df.SALES/df.SALES.sum()
price_weighted_ave = sum(df.price*df.weight)
print(price_weighted_ave)
```

Produces:

```
25.471658332900283
```